Unable to Add Product to Cart in Vue.js + Nuxt 3 + Pinia Store
I've been struggling for days to get my Vue.js application to add products to the cart using a Pinia store. My backend is built with Laravel, and I'm making API requests to add items to the cart. Despite trying various solutions, I keep encountering issues where the product isn't added to the cart.
The Issue:
When I attempt to add a product to the cart, I expect the product to be added and the cart to be updated. However, the product is not added. Below are the relevant parts of my code.
Vue.js Code (Pinia Store):
// stores/CartStore.ts
import { defineStore, acceptHMRUpdate } from "pinia";
import { addProductToCart, getCartData } from '@/services/api';
import { notify } from "@kyvg/vue3-notification";

interface CartItem {
  product_detail_id: number;
  name: string;
  product_image: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
}

const useCartStore = defineStore("CartStore", {
  state: () => ({
    cartItems: [] as CartItem[],
  }),
  actions: {
    async addProductToCart(productDetailId: number, quantity: number) {
      try {
        const response = await addProductToCart(productDetailId, quantity);
        if (response.status) {
          await this.fetchCartData(); // Refresh cart data
          notify({
            type: "success",
            text: "Product has been added to cart successfully !",
            duration: 500,
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding product to cart:', error);
        notify({
          type: "error",
          text: "Failed to add product to cart",
          duration: 500,
        });
      }
    },
    async fetchCartData() {
      try {
        const response = await getCartData();
        if (response.status) {
          this.cartItems = response.data;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching cart data:', error);
      }
    },
    removeItemFromCart(productDetailId: number) {
      this.cartItems = this.cartItems.filter(cartItem => cartItem.product_detail_id !== productDetailId);
      notify({
        type: "success",
        text: "Product has been removed from cart successfully !",
        duration: 500,
      });
    },
  },
  getters: {
    numberOfProductsInCart(state) {
      return state.cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity, 0);
    },
    totalAmountOfProductsInCart(state) {
      return state.cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + (item.price * item.quantity), 0);
    },
    productsInCart(state) {
      return state.cartItems;
    },
  },
});

// make sure to pass the right store definition, `useAuth` in this case.
if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useCartStore, import.meta.hot));
}

export default useCartStore;

API Service:
// services/api.ts
import { useFetch } from 'nuxt/app';
import {
  ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_URL,
  CART_DATA_URL
} from '@/constants/urls';

// Carts Data
export const addProductToCart = async (productDetailId: number, quantity: number) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('product_detail_id', productDetailId.toString());
  formData.append('quantity', quantity.toString());

  const data = await useFetch(ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  });

  return data.value;
};

export const getCartData = async () => {
  const data = await useFetch(CART_DATA_URL);
  return data.value;
};

The Constants URLS
//constants/urls.ts
export const API_BASE_URL = 'https://example.com/api';

// Carts Data
export const ADD_PRODUCT_TO_CART_URL: string = `${API_BASE_URL}/carts-data`;
export const ADD_BUNDLE_TO_CART_URL: string = `${API_BASE_URL}/carts-data`;
export const CART_DATA_URL: string = `${API_BASE_URL}/carts-data`;


Laravel Controller:
// app/Http/Controllers/User/AddToCartController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\User\StoreCartRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\User\AddToCartResource;
use App\Models\CartItem;
use App\Services\User\AddToCartService;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AddToCartController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(protected AddToCartService $addToCartService)
    {
    }

    public function store(StoreCartRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            $this->addToCartService->createCartItem($request->validated());
            return response()->success('Product added to cart Successfully');
        } catch (Exception) {
            return response()->fail();
        }
    }
}

Laravel Request:
// app/Http/Requests/User/StoreCartRequest.php

namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StoreCartRequest extends FormRequest
{
    protected function prepareForValidation(): void
    {
        $this->merge([
            'user_id' => Auth::id() ?: null,
            'session_id' => Auth::check() ? null : $this->session()->getId(),
        ]);
    }

    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => 'nullable|integer|exists:users,id',
            'session_id' => 'nullable|string',
            'product_detail_id' => [
                'integer',
                'exists:product_details,id',
                'required_without:bundle_id'
            ],
            'quantity' => [
                'required',
                'integer',
                'min:1',
            ],
        ];
    }
}

What I've Tried:

Verified the API endpoint using curl which returns a successful response.
Checked the payload being sent from the frontend to ensure it matches the API requirements.
Ensured that the backend routes and controllers are correctly configured and working.

Expected Behavior:
When a product is added to the cart, it should trigger the API call, add the product, and update the cart state accordingly.
Actual Behavior:
The product does not get added to the cart. However, the API returns a successful response when tested with curl.
Console Logs

api.ts:189 [nuxt] [useFetch] Component is already mounted, please use
$fetch instead. See
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching
product-slug-1:1 Access to fetch at
'https://example.com/api/carts-data' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. api.ts:189
POST https://example.com/api/carts-data net::ERR_FAILED 403
(Forbidden)

Any help or pointers on what I might be doing wrong or missing would be greatly appreciated!

This is a CORS configuration problem on your API side. CORS issues will only be encountered when making requests from a server, so this explains why you don't see them when using curl or other API tools. They happen because the API server does not allow requests from other servers like the one running on your localhost and being accessed through your browser.
Your error is telling you that there's no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header present on the response from your API so the request is blocked. You could set the following on your CORS preflight when returning responses from the API to allow requests from all origins:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Check out this guide for general information about enabling CORS.
For Laravel it looks like you need to use this configuration.
For a bunch more information specific to Laravel it looks like this guide is a good resource.
